# Footer won't stick on bottom when I go to the ask page

Tags: html, css, tumblr, tumblr-themes

I'm fixing this theme in tumblr, and the only problem that I'm facing is the footer one because on the main page its sticking well but when I transferred into the pages such as the submit page and the ask page it would just go up into the welcome message part.

```
#footer {
- height:55px; width:1200px; background:{color:footer bg}; clear: both;
z-index:-999px; position: absolute; bottom: -55px; left: calc(50% -
600px);
}

#footer .inner { 

 - color: {color:footer text}; margin:0 auto; padding: 16px; font-family:'roboto' sans-serif; font-weight:bold;text-align:center;font-size:10px; letter-spacing:2px; text-transform:uppercase;

}

#footer a { 

 - color: {color:footer text}; padding: 5px; font-size: 10px;
   letter-spacing: 2px;

}

#footer a:hover {

 - color: {color:menu hover text}; background: {color:menu hover bg};
```

The main theme can be seen at swanepoelofph.tumblr.com where the footer is alright and this is the part where the footer goes up http://swanepoelofrph.tumblr.com/a and http://swanepoelofrph.tumblr.com/submit , just like also in the rules, icon styles pages too.

The code that I have made and tried goes like this ( I just do this one ). I'm not sure if I could post the whole html in here but if there are a questions or you would like to see the whole I could send a link.

Comment: link is broken..please check and also post the demo link where you are facing the issue..thanx

Comment: @Leothelion sorry didn't noticed it earlier but edited it already. Thanks.

Comment: @KrishnaSantos sorry I was at school. I've notice that u have z-index: -999px; z-index doesn't use px. Only numbers :)

Comment: @SebastianManuelli Oh so that's why it didn't worked. Thanks once more :)

Comment: @KrishnaSantos you're welcome

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem of the tumblr page : 
Just change the container and the footer position to relative

```
.container {
    position: relative;
    ... other styles ...
}

#footer {
    position: relative;
    ... other styles ...
}
```

Comment: Okay this one helped, but the pagination moved under the welcome part ?  I don't know how to bring it back above the footer again. But on the pages part it did worked !!